# How to turn off the "Hit <Return> to see next plot" prompt plot3D?

Tags: r, plot

When using `persp3D` in package `plot3D`, there's only one plot produced but I still have to respond to the "Hit <Return> to see next plot" prompt. Is there a way to turn it off?

More generally, when there *are* multiple plots, do packages typically provide a way to specify a particular plot to show, similar to the `which = c(1:3, 5)` argument in `plot.lm`?

Comment: When I tried a MWE `persp3D(z = volcano, main = "volcano", clab = c("height", "m"))`, it does have the prompt even though `getOption("device.ask.default")` is `FALSE`. Don't you get the same prompt?

Comment: I don't get the prompt in Rterm or in RStudio. Windows, 64-bit, plot3D 1.0-2.

Answer (score 33):

I ran into the same problem as you did and fixed it by the following code:

```
par(ask=F)
```

I hope it will help.

Answer (score 6):

At some point, par(ask = F) was deprecated in favor of devAskNewPage.

In my copy of R 3.5.1, the following code plots without asking...

```
devAskNewPage(ask = FALSE)
# plot command here
```

Comment: seems it doesn't work with `png` device